# Can not deserialize instance of ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token for custom Repository query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm receiving the following Exception while attempting to retrieve a Collection of FooBar objects from a Spring Repository:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@35010a6b; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@35010a6b; line: 1, column: 1]

Everything works swimmingly when I use the default Repository `findAll()`, but fails when I try to implement a custom query. What am I missing here? I'm using an in-memory H2 database. My schema is from a legacy system I have no control over. Thanks in advance!

**Schema**

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo_bar
(
    foobarid      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY                      NOT NULL,
    fooid         INTEGER DEFAULT 0                        NOT NULL,
    barid         INTEGER DEFAULT 0                        NOT NULL,
    start_date    TIMESTAMP(0),
    end_date      TIMESTAMP(0),
    last_modified TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NOT NULL,
    data          TEXT                                     NOT NULL
);
```

**FooBar Model**

```java
@Entity(name = "foo_bar")
public final class FooBar {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "foobarid", nullable = false)
    private Integer fooBarId;
    @Column(name = "fooid", nullable = false)
    private Integer fooId;
    @Column(name = "barid", nullable = false)
    private Integer barId;
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    @Type(type = "com.example.LocalDateTimeUserType")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    @Type(type = "com.example.LocalDateTimeUserType")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;
    @Column(name = "last_modified", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "com.example.LocalDateTimeUserType")
    private LocalDateTime dateLastModified = LocalDateTime.now();
    @Column(name = "data", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "clob not null")
    @Lob
    private String data;

    // ... getters, setters, equals, hashcode and toString ...

}
```

**FooBar Repository**

```java
@Repository
public interface FooBarRepository extends JpaRepository<FooBar, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT fb FROM foo_bar fb WHERE fb.fooId = :fooId")
    Collection<FooBar> findAllForFooId(@Param("fooId") Integer fooId);

}
```

**FooBar Controller**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo/bar")
public final class FooBarController {

    private final FooBarRepository fooBarRepository;

    @Autowired
    public FooBarController(FooBarRepository fooBarRepository) {
        this.fooBarRepository = fooBarRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{fooId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<FooBar> retrieveAllFooBarForFoo(@PathVariable("fooId") Integer fooId) {
        return fooBarRepository.findAllForFooId(fooId);
    }

}
```

**FooBar Controller Integration Test**

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(TestApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class FooBarControllerTest {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:9989/foo/bar/";

    @Test
    public void retrieveAllFooBarForFoo() throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
        final ParameterizedTypeReference<ArrayList<FooBar>> fooBarType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ArrayList<FooBar>>() {};
        ResponseEntity<ArrayList<FooBar>> response = restTemplate
            .exchange(
                BASE_URL + "230",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                fooBarType
            );
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
        assertTrue(response.getBody().size() > 0);
    }

}
```

**LocalDateTimeUserType** (found somewhere on StackOverflow)

```java
public final class LocalDateTimeUserType implements UserType, StringRepresentableType<LocalDateTime>, Serializable {

    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = new int[]{Types.TIMESTAMP};

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return LocalDateTime.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        if (x == y) {
            return true;
        }
        if (x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        }
        LocalDateTime dtx = (LocalDateTime) x;
        LocalDateTime dty = (LocalDateTime) y;
        return dtx.equals(dty);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return object.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Object timestamp = StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeGet(resultSet, names, session, owner);
        if (timestamp == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return ((Timestamp) timestamp).toLocalDateTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, null, index, session);
        }
        else {
            LocalDateTime ldt = ((LocalDateTime) value);
            Instant instant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
            Date timestamp = Date.from(instant);
            StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, timestamp, index, session);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(LocalDateTime value) throws HibernateException {
        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime fromStringValue(String string) throws HibernateException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(string);
    }

}
```

**Gradle Dependencies**

```
dependencies {

    // General
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:19.0"
    compile "com.h2database:h2:1.4.192"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.7.4"
    compile "org.json:json:20140107"

    // Spring
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.3.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.3.5.RELEASE"

    // Test Dependencies
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.3.5.RELEASE"

}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No I haven't. I ended up taking a different approach.

Comment: What did your JSON look like?